# Increase a number with behave mswin

Tags: key-bindings

Is there a way to increase the number under the coursor while still using `behave mswin`? Since `behave mswin` overwrites CTRL_A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In itself, `:behave mswin` does not remap `<C-A>`. But there is a script mentioned in `:help behave` - called `mswin.vim` - which calls `:behave mswin` *and* remaps <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> etc.

For clarifications which mappings and settings are applied by `mswin.vim`, open and read the file in your favorite editor. I suggest `:e $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim`.

#### Minimal

Just call `:behave mswin` but don't `:source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim`.
This will give `:behave mswin` but not map any other keys.

#### Unmap

Source the file but unmap everything that's not wanted. It would look like this in vimrc:

```
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
unmap <C-A>
unmap <C-X>
```

Figuring out how much sense it makes to source a file that defines mappings only to unmap them later is left as an exercise to the reader.

#### Other mapping

To have both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> select everything and have a key to increment numbers, you can assign a different mapping to the latter function.

It would look like this in vimrc:

```
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
nnoremap <leader>a <C-A>
```

In this example, it will make *leader*+<kbd>A</kbd> increment numbers while retaining <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all. The best of both worlds, if you will.